# Как вызвать кастомный метод контроллера используя форму?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня есть метод в контроллере

```
def custom_method
  @object = Customer.find_by(attribute: params[:attribute])
  @object.self_method if @object.present?
end
```

маршрут

```
resources :customers do
  collection do
    patch :custom_method
  end
end
```

форма

```
= form_with(url: custom_method_customers_path, method: :patch) do
  = text_field_tag :attribute
  = submit_tag "Submit"
```

Что я делаю не так?
Хотелось бы увидеть актуальное решение с примерами, спасибо!

Comment: Когда у вас что-то не получается, не забывайте описывать, какой именно неправильный результат вы получаете - логи, стектрейс ошибки и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Методом тыка пришёл к решению

```
= form_tag custom_method_customres_path do
  = text_field_tag :attribute
  = submit_tag "Submit"
```

routes.rb

```
resources :customers do
  collection do
    post :custom_method
  end
end
```